# Qt CSS Image over Background in Same Widget? (Teamspeak Theme)

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to create a new theme for TeamSpeak 3, and I'm needing an image with a transparent background to hover and scale above a background. How do I do this?

I tried adding regular image:, image-position:, etc. under background-image:, but it doesn't work.

EDIT: Here is the CSS for the chat I'm needing to add the image to.

```
ChatTab {
border-image: url('Styles/Valor/Images/chatarea.png');
border-right: 5px transparent;
border-left: 5px transparent;
background-color: #121212;
text-transform: normal;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #cccccc;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
show-decoration-selected: 0;
background-image:url('Styles/Valor/Images/top2.png');
background-position:right bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-xy;
background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

Comment: Show your css. Btw, did you try to use `border-image` instead of `image`?

Comment: There is already a border image. Not sure of what else to do. Might just have to make a large image with the shield in the corner and set it as a static background. Is it possible to make the background scale to the chat's size without distortion?

Comment: It is not possible to scale raster (non-vector) images without distortion.

Comment: sorry I meant scale the background and keep the same aspect ratio. I need the shield to stay the same shape. Is it possible to have the background scale and keep the same aspect ratio even if it's larger than the chat box? If not I'll just have to live with the shield getting cut off for some people if their chat box is small.

Comment: Did you read this? - http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties